# Python: See for which of the values in a list the "if any"-statement was true

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a list of users (uniqueUsers) that I've sorted out from a Log-file.

Now I'd like to see which user is doing what and at what point and have used this if statement to check the entire log-file that I've read in:

```
if any(x in line for x in uniqueUsers) and "borrow" in line or "return" in line:
```

What I've done after this is to use a regular expression to get the user's ID from the line, but I started wondering if there would be any way for me to in a very short form get the user that Python found from this condition:

```
any(x in line for x in uniqueUsers)
```

Comment: Be aware that `and` binds stronger than `or`, so your condition is currently equivalent to `(any(x in line for x in uniqueUsers) and ("borrow" in line)) or ("return" in line)`. I guess you may want `any(x in line for x in uniqueUsers) and ("borrow" in line or "return" in line)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition to a predicate and store the result (by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression):

```
users_in_line = [u for u in uniqueUsers if u in line]
if users_in_line and "borrow" in line or "return" in line:
    # do something with list users_in_line
    ...
```

This uses the fact that empty lists act "falsy" in a boolean context, while non-empty lists (no matter their content) act "truthy".